# When I update my model in ng repeat the directive ng-show does not change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I have a page where I update my model dynamically

```
<div ng-repeat="action in actions">
  <div ng-show="action.showMyDiv">Hello </div>
<div>
```

when I update my model dynamically from an action in the current page with

```
 $scope.actions[id]['showMyDiv']= true,
```

the div does not display. 
Please , could you help me ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: A fiddle might help explain the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating the value manually, you can wrap it in $scope.$apply():

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.actions[id]['showMyDiv']= true
})
```

EDIT:

2 cents on $scope.$apply:
The way angular works out bindings is by doing dirty checking at every render (plenty sources about the process if you search around). As you use a angular default method (ng-click, for instance) a flag is set to warn the  app that the page needs "refreshing", and you see the changes happen.

If you change anything manually, you need to warn the app that it needs refreshing, and you can do that with $apply.
See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/YnnKm/) for clarification. Notice that two changes are made "manually", at 2s and 4s in, using window.timeout (which you shouldn't use, but rather use the $timeout service), but only after the second one are the changes propagated to the view.